# How to apply VBA on below cell?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2:C2")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A2:C2")) = 0 Then
            Range("D2").ClearContents
        Else
            Range("D2").Formula = "=SUM(A2:C2)"
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
End Sub
```

I want that the way this VBA is currently working on one ROW, in the same way it should also do the ROW below.

Comment: As in Target intersects with A3:C3 or just adjust D3 as well with the conditions on A3:C3?

Comment: Replace both occurrences of `D2` with `D2:D3`.

Answer (score 0):

`Formula2R1C1` makes it easy to create relative formulas.  I don't usually wrote the `Formula2R1C1` formulas myself.  instead, I add a normal formula to the ActiveCell and then print the `Formula2R1C1` to the Immediate Window.

[image: Immediate Window]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2:C3")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A2:C2")) = 0 Then
            Target.EntireRow.Range("D1").ClearContents
        Else
            Target.EntireRow.Range("D1").Formula2R1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-3]:RC[-1])"
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Will this work on the below row as well?

Comment: @AshokKumar `Range("A2:C3")` dictates how many rows are affected.  `Range("A2:C4")` will add one more row.  If you need to create a dynamic range that is a different question.

Answer (score 0):

This will handle multi-cell updates across rows:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, rw As Range, c As Range, rngSum As Range
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A2:C100")) 'for example
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        For Each rw In rng.Rows 'check each changed row...
            Set rngSum = rw.EntireRow.Range("A1:C1") 'range is *relative* to `rw`
            Set c = rw.EntireRow.Columns("D")
            If Application.CountA(rngSum) = 0 Then
                c.ClearContents
            Else
                c.Formula = "=SUM(" & rngSum.Address(False, False) & ")"
            End If
        Next rw
    End If
End Sub
```